# ¿Cómo se pronuncia correctamente "ballet"?

Tags: pronunciación

Siempre la he oído pronunciar como «balet» (a veces omitiendo la pronunciación de la «t»), como si solo tuviera una «**l**». Pero, al contener una «**ll**», ¿no debería pronunciarse algo así como «ba**y**et», con el sonido habitual de la «**ll**», como la palabra «**valle**»?

El Diccionario de la Lengua recoge:

> 1. m. Danza clásica de conjunto, representada sobre un escenario.
> 2. m. Música para *ballet*.
> 3. m. Compañía de *ballet*.

pero nada de la pronunciación.

Comment: Fácilmente lo encuentras en la RAE http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=ballet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la entrada del DPD que enlaza @DGaleano:

> ***[ballet](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=ballet)***.1. Voz francesa (**pron. [balé]**) que significa ‘danza clásica’ y ‘compañía que interpreta este tipo de danza’. Por tratarse de un extranjerismo crudo, debe escribirse con resalte tipográfico. Su plural es *ballets*.
>   2. Aunque es palabra asentada en el uso internacional con su grafía originaria, puede adaptarse fácilmente al español en la forma *balé* (pl. *balés*).

Es decir, que se pronuncia "balé" porque en realidad es un vocablo francés, no español. En español se escribe *balé*, como suena, pero nadie usa esa forma, porque la otra es la más conocida.

Comment: Es curioso que la Real Academia la recoja como voz francesa y que se pronuncie "a la francesa" - creía que estaba ya aceptada como española